# Rails can't find version of the gem it already has

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`money` gem was installed several months ago, then deleted, and now I'm trying to install it again with some additional Gems.

```
$ `bundle install` gives:
    Using money (6.1.1)
    Using monetize (0.3.0)
    Using money-rails (0.10.0)
```

Gem file:

```
gem 'money', '6.1.1'
gem 'money-rails'
gem 'eu_central_bank'
```

but Rails can't start, because of error:

```
`spec_set.rb:92:in `block` in materialize: Could not find money-6.1.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

On development machine it works well, it happens only on production. How to solve this?

Comment: What if you try specifying a source? `gem 'money', '6.1.1', git: 'https://github.com/RubyMoney/money.git'`

Comment: What is the result of the command run `gem list money` on production? Are you using rvm?

Comment: Yes, I'm using rvm, about first part of the question - I will find out in a few days, can't enter the server now

Comment: `gem list money` echos only `*** LOCAL GEMS ***` and nothing after that